# how can a connection current state be closed if it hasn't been closed

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, database-connection

We have an application that calls a few stored procedure several thousand times throughout a run.  The application uses the following SQLLogger object as a logging mechanism.  that is to say the object is instantiated once, and the method WriteLogLine is called after each execution.  we recently changed the code to run on several threads.  Once we get above five we get the following error.  I've tried several things but haven't found a solution yet. any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated
thank you

System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteNonQuery requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.GetOpenConnection(String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(DbAsyncResult result, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at SQLLogger.WriteLogLine(String LogEntry, String methodName, String jobID, Boolean CustomerNotification, Nullable`1 iQuantity)
   at MainModule.Main()

```
string ApplicationName;
        Guid AppRunid;


        SqlConnection db;



        public SQLLogger(string _ApplicationName, Guid _AppRunID,string LogDbConnectionString)
        {
            ApplicationName = _ApplicationName;           
            AppRunid = _AppRunID;

            db = new SqlConnection(LogDbConnectionString);
            db.Open();
        }

        public void WriteLogLine(string LogEntry ,string methodName,string jobID =null,Boolean CustomerNotification=false,int? iQuantity=null)
        {


            SqlCommand SQL = new SqlCommand("LogApplicationEvent", db);
            SQL.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@appName", ApplicationName);
            SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", LogEntry);
            SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jobID", jobID);
            SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AppRunID", AppRunid );
            SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerMessage", CustomerNotification );
            SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MethodName", methodName);
            SQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", iQuantity);
            SQL.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Console.WriteLine(String.Format(DateTime.Now.ToString(), "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + " " + LogEntry +" "+jobID+" "+ iQuantity.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Singleton pattern with thread safety is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Make the logger class static and make the SqlConnection static. I think there are too many objects in your code. Make it static so that it exists for each usage. Make the WriteLogLine static also and make sure the connection is not getting closed in any code.